# R - Multiple Conditional Looping

Tags: r, data-modeling

Need help in running the R code for the below sample scenario:

```
Set_1 = data.frame(Enc=c(23345,23345,23349,23349,23349,23354,23367,23367,23372,23372,23382),
                   CPT = c("97110","97140","99396","36415","99000","99203O","73030","99024","99213O","36415","81002"),
                   Paid_Status = c("Paid","Non Paid","Paid","Non Paid","Non Paid","Paid","Paid","Non Paid","Paid","Non Paid","Non Paid"))

Set_2 = data.frame(Main_CPT = c("26010","26010","26010","26010","26025","26025","26025","26025","26025","26025","26034",26034","26034","26034","26034"),
                   Child_CPT = c("01810",01995","0213T","0216T","64490","64491","64492","64493","64494","64495","64530","69990","99148","99149","99150"))
```

From the 1st data, I need to verify the `Enc` wise rows having `CPT` with `Paid_Status`, from each enc no. one of the `CPT` is `Main_CPT` and other `CPT` are `Child_CPT` and the details can be compared with the 2nd data set.

Now, I want to look at the enc wise with the one `CPT` that matches with the `Main_CPT` of the 2nd data set and for the status of that particular CPT is paid, new column in 1st data set to be as "P" in that row, then the remaining CPT of that Enc should match with the Child CPT of the 2nd data set and the corresponding rows in new column of 1st data set should be "A".

Comment: Welcome! Please, specify well your request and datasets.

Comment: In the 1st data set, from the enc no. 23349 having 3 observations with 3 unique CPT codes, one of the code should match with the Main CPT of the 2nd data set and the that corresponding CPT from the 1st data set status is paid!, then flag the CPT with "P" and the remaining CPT codes fot that particular Enc no. has to match with Child CPT of the 2nd data set, and that CPT has to be flagged with "A".  Same way for every Enc. no. Thank you.

Comment: You are telling not showing us. Please show with data your desired result and earnest attempt to better illustrate your needs.